# hls.js can we flip the video horizontally or vertically because doing it with css, it flips the controller too :(

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, http-live-streaming, video-player, hls.js

I have a working hls.js player.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js@latest"></script>
<video id="video"></video>
<script>
  var video = document.getElementById('video');
  var videoSrc = 'https://test-streams.mux.dev/x36xhzz/x36xhzz.m3u8';
  if (Hls.isSupported()) {
    var hls = new Hls();
    hls.loadSource(videoSrc);
    hls.attachMedia(video);
  } else if (video.canPlayType('application/vnd.apple.mpegurl')) {
    video.src = videoSrc;
  }
</script>
```

but when I do `<video style="transform:scaleX(-1);" ...`  it flip the video BUT flip the controller too :(

is there an other way to do it ?

some webcam tends to flip the image....